# Link dies on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python-2.7, django-1.7

Short version:

After ajax call, link turns into plain text, but back to link on page refresh.

Details:

I have a notification system in place (like Stack Overflow and whatnot).  The notifications are either in a dropdown subtemplate:

notification_menu_list.html

{% load display_tags %}
{% load item_tags %}

```
<div id='notification_header'>{{ request.user|count_unread_notifications }} notification{{ request.user|count_unread_notifications|pluralize}}</div>
        <ul id='notification_box'>
          {% for notification in request.user|get_notifications|slice:"6" %}
            {% if notification.active %}
              <li class='unread notification' id='{{notification.pk}}'>{{notification.headline|safe}}</li>
            {% else %}
              <li class='read notification' id='{{notification.pk}}'>{{notification.headline|safe}}</li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          <li class='notification all_notifications_link'><a href='{% url "notifications" %}'>Show all</a></li>
      </ul>
```

or in a django-table with more details:

tables.py

```
class NotificationTable(tables.Table):

    tr_class = tables.BooleanColumn(
        visible=False,
        empty_values=(),
        accessor='active',
    )

    selection = tables.columns.CheckBoxColumn(
        accessor="pk",
        attrs={"th__input": {"onclick": "toggle(this)"}},
        orderable=False)

    message = tables.Column(
        accessor='body',
        verbose_name='Message')

    def render_message(self, value):
      return mark_safe(value)

    created_date = tables.DateTimeColumn()

    def render_tr_class(self, value):
        if value is False:
            return 'read'
        elif value is True:
            return 'unread'

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
```

They both render correctly.  On the table, I can select notifications, and click 'Mark as Read' which processes the form through an ajax call and sets 'active' to False.  On the dropdown, clicking a notification (which is often a link) will trigger an ajax call to mark_single_notification_as_read:

views.py:

```
def mark_notifications_as_read(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_pks = request.POST.getlist('selection')
        selected_pks = [int(pk) for pk in selected_pks[0].split(',') if pk != 'on']
        Notification.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_pks).update(active=False)
    table = build_notifications_table(request).as_html()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(table), content_type='application/json')


def mark_single_notification_as_read(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        notification_id = request.POST.get('notification_id')
        Notification.objects.filter(pk=int(notification_id)).update(active=False)
        return render(request,
                      'notifications/notifications_menu_list.html',
                      {})
    else:
        print 'not post'
```

Either way, once the ajax completes, the links turn into plain text.  If I refresh the page, they are back.  I can't figure out why.  Any thoughts?

EDITED:

Forgot the ajax.  Why in the world would *that* be important?

```
$("#notification_container").on('click', 'li.unread', function(){
      notification_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'mark_single_notification_as_read' %}",
        data: {'notification_id' : notification_id}, 
        success: function(data){
          $('#notification_container').html(data);
        }
      });
```

Comment: The link changes back on reload because the original source is restored. That means that something you do during the AJAX operation replaces the links with plain text.

Comment: That's what I figured... but I can't see what.  Forgot to add ajax above--adding now.

Comment: You're overwriting everything in the #notification_container when the AJAX call is successful. Is that where these links are?

Comment: Yes, but the links are the bodies of the Notification objects--stored in the database.  I return them with a query

Comment: `mark_notifications_as_read` builds the same table (updated, obviously) as the original template does.

Comment: removing the `as_html` from ` table = build_notifications_table(request).as_html()` in mark_notifications_as_read fixed the problem there... still having trouble with mark_single_notification_as_read (and not sure why that fixed it)

Comment: And I fixed the other one by just changing the class through ajax instead of replacing the div... it's good now, but I'd still like to know why the original didn't work.

Comment: I'd have to see the output from the original.